# How can i convert join queries into subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to ask is it possible to convert join queries into subquery ? Like if i have a query like

```
select * from Losa_Cust_Reject_App rejectApp 
inner join 
    Losa_Cust losaCust 
on 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No = losaCust.app_Ref_No 
where 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No != '0000001912' and  rejectApp.app_Dt >= '23-SEP-2012' 
and
    rejectApp.cust_Id1 = 'A111111111' and rejectApp.cust_Id1_Type = '01';
```

can i convert this query into subquery ? Mean remove the inner join ?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing that? One of the first operations the optimiser will do is to try to transform a subquery back to a join.

Comment: Oh, rejectApp.app_Dt >= '23-SEP-2012' should be rejectApp.app_Dt >= to_char('23-SEP-2012','DD-MON-YYYY') or rejectApp.app_Dt >= date '2012-09-23'

Comment: Actually i just want to know. Actually i want to ask this because suppose i don't know the association between tables, like one to one or many to many or one to many, and i don't know on which column i put join and i want to retrieve data between two tables ....In this case is it possisble to convert above query into subquery ?

Comment: Are you using the join only to check for existence of the `app_Ref_No` in the `Losa_Cust` table? If so, what other tables can the `app_Ref_No` refer to then?

Comment: actually `'A111111111'` and `'01'` are the `cust_Id1` and cust_Id1_Type in loas_cust table respectively. Here i hard-coded the values. In actual it is like `rejectApp.cust_Id1 = losaCust.cust_Id1 and rejectApp.cust_Id1_Type = losaCust.cust_Id1_type;`

Comment: You lost me now, what do you want to query?

Comment: As it stands you can't convert it to a subquery, because you are selecting all the columns from both tables. If you just wanted to retrieve tha values for one of them then it would be more compatible with a subquery-based approach.

Comment: May be i am not clear what i want, but i want to convert this query into subquery `select * from Losa_Cust_Reject_App rejectApp 
inner join 
    Losa_Cust losaCust 
on 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No = losaCust.app_Ref_No 
where 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No != '0000001912' and  rejectApp.app_Dt >= '23-SEP-2012' 
and
    rejectApp.cust_Id1 = losaCust.Id1 and rejectApp.cust_Id1_Type = losaCust.Id1_Type; ` but as David said that it is not possible beause i am getting all the columns, not specific column ...